# if else statement in shiny not working properly

Tags: r, shiny, dt, shiny-reactivity, shinyapps

Below is a script I've been working on. You will notice that the reactive statement, `table_data()`, is where the heavy lifting takes place. When you run the app, you will see all three filters are empty. They are suppose to be empty, but the rendered table should be producing a table that represents the filtered output in that final `else if` statement:

`res <- df %>% group_by(level1) %>% summarise(total=sum(sales))`, so when the app loads, the first thing you should see is this:

[image]

But it does not produce that. It produces an empty table. I'm struggling to understand what I'm doing incorrectly. Here is the script:

```
level1 <- c('1','1','1','1','1','1','2','2','2','2','2','2','3','3','3','3','3','3')
level2 <- c('1A','1A','1B','1B','1C','1C','2A','2A','2B','2B','2C','2C','3A','3A','3B','3B','3C','3C')
level3 <- c('Jones','Smith','Johnson','James','Evans','Long','Roth','Goldberg','Ramos','Winston','Levin','Jackson','Fishman','Drake','Quinn','Lackey','Scott','McGuire')
sales <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18)

df <- cbind(level1,level2,level3,sales) %>% as.data.frame() %>% mutate(level1 = as.character(level1), level2 = as.character(level2), level3 = as.character(level3), sales = as.integer(sales))

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(8,
           width = 10, offset = 1,
           tags$h3("Select Area"),
           panel(
            selectInput('lev1', label = 'Level 1', c(unique(sort(df$level1))), multiple = TRUE),
            uiOutput("level2"),
            uiOutput("level3")
           ),
           DT::dataTableOutput(outputId = "test")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$level2 <- renderUI({
    selectizeInput("lev2", "Level 2", multiple = TRUE, c(unique(sort(df$level2[df$level1 ==input$lev1]))))
  }) 

  output$level3 <- renderUI({
    selectizeInput("lev3", "Level 3", multiple = TRUE, c(unique(sort(df$level3[df$level2 ==input$lev2]))))
  })


table_data <- reactive({

  if(!is.null(input$lev1) & is.null(input$lev2) & is.null(input$lev3)) #When lev1 is not null, but the other two are
    res <- df %>% filter(level1 %in% input$lev1) %>% group_by(level1,level2) %>% summarise(total=sum(sales))
  else
    if(is.null(input$lev1) | !is.null(input$lev1) & !is.null(input$lev2) & is.null(input$lev3)) #When lev2 is not null, lev3 is null, and lev1 can be either/or
      res <- df %>% filter(level2 %in% input$lev2) %>% group_by(level2,level3) %>% summarise(total=sum(sales))
    else
      if(is.null(input$lev1) | !is.null(input$lev1) & is.null(input$lev2) | !is.null(input$lev2) & !is.null(input$lev3)) #When lev3 is not null, lev1 can be either/or, and lev2 can be either/or
        res <- df %>% filter(level3 %in% input$lev3) %>% group_by(level1,level2,level3) %>% summarise(total=sum(sales))
      else
        if(is.null(input$lev1) & is.null(input$lev2) & is.null(input$lev3)) #When lev1 is null, lev2 is null, and lev3 is null (THIS ONE IS NOT WORKING CORRECTLY)
      res <- df %>% group_by(level1) %>% summarise(total=sum(sales))

})

output$test <- DT::renderDataTable({
  table_data()
})

}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Comment: Just use `all(is.null(x,y,z))` and maybe use curly brackets(for the last if statement nested in else)?

Comment: @NelsonGon -

Can you please show me what you mean? I changed the last one to 

`else {
        all(is.null(input$lev1,input$lev2,input$lev3)) 
      res <- df %>% group_by(level1) %>% summarise(total=sum(sales))
      }`

But no luck

Comment: On phone now. is.null takes one argument if I'm not mistaken, so you might need three. Also aren't you supposed to return res instead of storing it in a variable(not sure if it's different with shiny)?!

Comment: It seems to me that your second `if` condition is TRUE at the start-up: `is.null(input$lev1) | !is.null(input$lev1) & !is.null(input$lev2) & ....`. So you get `df %>% filter(level2 %in% input$lev2) %>% ......` which is a 0-row tibble, because `input$lev2` is NULL.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent so what would that final output look like?